# code not working properly after inserting large volume of data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a gridview for showing employees in standby mobilization.Initially around 2000 employees are loaded in gridview.My problem is that, in mobilization page,when we mobilize employees, data is inserting correctly,but fillgrid is not getting called

Its working fine in my local system,but not in the server.Is it because of large volume of data.Every other function is working correctly....

Heres my code for inserting

```
int i = clsMob.InsertMobilizationDetails(dsMobilizn.GetXml());
if (i>0)
{
   FillGrid();
   ClearAll();
   string str = "<script>alert('Successfully mobilized the selected employees')</script>";
                 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Validation Error", str, false);
                 return;
}
```

Function InsertMobilizationDetails

```
public int InsertMobilizationDetails(string xml)
{
    Database_Operations dbo = new Database_Operations("TransMob_InDetails", true);
    dbo.AddParameter("@xmlMob", xml);        
    return dbo.ExecuteQuery();  //returns value as 1     
}
```

Comment: "is not executing correctly" is far too vague to get a diagnosis. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Please post relevant parts of source code. Part of the code where you add a script tag is will not affect performance. I would add the source code for `InsertMobilizationDetails` and `FillGrid`.

Comment: It seems you need some pagination there. 2000 records are a lot for showing them in the UI

Comment: No Error is showing.I'm getting 'i 'as 1 after insertion,but it seems some thing is going wrong when application is running in server

Answer (score 0):

if the records number exceed more than 2000 there might me an issue with service message size, the default message size would be some 65536. Increase the message size and try to load the app.

Comment: After insertion is completed i again calls fillgrid method,which also loads the gridview.This function is not getting called...